# Xdebug как работает подсчет ссылок

Tags: php, xdebug

В документации есть пару фрагментов иллюстрирующих как именно это работает, но один момент не понятен, я проиллюстирую это ниже:

```
/// Example 1
$a = 10;
xdebug_debug_zval('a');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 10

/// Example 2
$a = 10;
$b = 10;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 10
/// b:(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 10

/// Example 3
$a = 10;
$b = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=2, is_ref=0),int 10
/// b:(refcount=2, is_ref=0),int 10

/// Example 4
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 10
/// b:(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 10

/// Example 5
$a = 10;
$b = $a;
$c = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b','c');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=3, is_ref=0),int 10
/// b:(refcount=3, is_ref=0),int 10
/// c:(refcount=3, is_ref=0),int 10

/// Example 6
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
$c = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b','c');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 10
/// b:(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 10
/// c:(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 10

/// Example 7
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
$c = &$a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b','c');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=3, is_ref=1),int 10
/// b:(refcount=3, is_ref=1),int 10
/// c:(refcount=3, is_ref=1),int 10
```

Исходя из всех примеров самый нелогичный для меня оказался `Example 6`, я реально не понимаю почему когда мы дебажим мы не получаем во всех строках следующую запись

```
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=3, is_ref=1),int 10
/// b:(refcount=3, is_ref=1),int 10
/// c:(refcount=3, is_ref=0),int 10
```

Объясните в чем здесь дело?

Comment: Какую версию PHP рассматриваете? В 5 и в 7 оно, какбы, несколько по разному работает.

Comment: @rjhdby PHP 5.6, но я уже разобрался с этим, у меня есть более новые вопросы, если знаете ответ, милости прошу =)

Answer (score 1):

Пока нет никаких действий с переменной, она как-бы константа. И два раза под неё место не выделяется. Как только сделали ссылку на переменную (это уже действие) - создаётся новая "область памяти"

Вот объяснение в документации:

http://php.net/manual/ru/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php

Пример #3 Увеличение счетчика ссылок zval

```
<?php
$a = "new string";
$b = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval( 'a' );
?>
```

Результат выполнения данного примера:

```
a: (refcount=2, is_ref=0)='new string'
```

Счетчик ссылок здесь равен 2, т.к. **a и b ссылаются на один и тот же контейнер переменной. PHP достаточно умен, чтобы не копировать контейнер**, пока в этом нет необходимости.

Comment: Глянь на третий пример и на четвертый, потом попытайся сделать умозаключение. В третьем примере так называемая софт ссылка и пока действий не происходит то refcount = 2 - это все понятно. В четвертом примере хард ссылка и там тоже refcount = 2, все понятно, refcount при жесткой ссылке не изменится (если пытаться менять значение переменных-ссылок). Но 6ой пример мне не понятен там вроде сначала хард ссылка, потом софт ссылка, так почему refcount != 3 ?
P.S Ваш ответ пока слабо обоснован!

Comment: Действие - это когда мы меняем значение у переменной, пока мы одной переменной присвоили другой copy-on-write не произойдет, до тех пор пока мы не изменим значение. А присвоение по ссылке это почти то же самое что и присвоить (за исключением последствий) ни о каком изменении речи не идет.

Comment: Глянул на третий и четвёртый. Не вижу противоречий.
В третьем константа. На неё ссылается две переменные.
В четвёртом константа. На неё ссылается переменная и ссылка на переменную.

Comment: Попробуй сделай $a = 10; $b = $a; $a += 1; xdebug_debug_zval('a','b'); Должно получиться a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0) b: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)

Comment: "присвоение по ссылке это почти то же самое что и присвоить" - неверно.
Пусть $a = 10; $aa = &$a; $b = 10; $bb = &$b; Интерпретатору надо разделить сущности $a и $b для работы по ссылкам $aa и $bb. Поэтому он при присвоении ссылки создаёт новую zval (как-бы область памяти)